# (How) Was SPARQL influenced by erotetics?

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web

Erotetics is the logic of questions and answers. The field has been developed over the last hundred years and is nicely summarized by (Wisniewski 2015).

How, if at all, was SPARQL, the RDF query language, influenced by the research in that field?

- Wisniewski, Andrzej. "Semantics of questions." The handbook of contemporary semantic theory 3 (2015): 273. ([pdf](http://awisniew.home.amu.edu.pl/publikacje/wisniewskif1.pdf))

Comment: You could ask your question at semantic-web@w3.org (or one of the SPARQL authors personally). I suppose, the answer is "to the same extent as Prolog, Datalog, SQL", i. e. nohow. Possibly the difference between SPARQL query forms (`ASK`, `SELECT`, `DESCRIBE`, `CONSTRUCT`) corresponds to something in "erotetics". Or maybe more recent studies about SPARQL query containment are relevant. Perhaps SPARQL entailment regimes could be considered as different degrees of "logical omniscience", if erotetics deals with that problem.. P.S. I never read even Belnap & Steel and just imagine what erotetics is.

Comment: I just did https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/semantic-web/2018Dec/0133.html . Though I am trying to get them to come here to answer these questions :-)